# calling a list from inside a class in a different script python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have created a remote object style property database. I am trying to create a search function to:

1. search by postcode
2. search by price range

I am struggling to call the dictionary-style list that is within the warehouse script i.e.

```
class Warehouse(object):
    def __init__(self):
#I WANT TO CALL THIS LIST HERE (NOTE IT IS DYNAMIC AND MAY HAVE MORE/LESS)
        self.contents ={"1000":["John", "1", "CF24 4AN", 200000], "1001":["Bob", "2", "CF10 1EN", 250000]}
```

by code used to visit the warehouse and that the search function is contained is in a different script, namely below

```
#THIS IS THE SEARCH FUNCTION IM TRYING TO CREATE
def search_postcode(warehouse):
    searchfor = str(input("Please enter a postcode: "))
    for k in warehouse:
        for v in warehouse[k]:
            if searchfor in v:
                print(k, ":", warehouse[k])
    return None

    exit
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Proxy' object is not iterable.
```

So my question is, how can I search the contents list in the `__init__` of the Warehouse class through a function defined in a completely different script?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "call a list"? Also, can you reduce your code to a minimal example? I bet 80% has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: edited out most of the irrelevant code. worth noting that there is an add and remove function in the warehouse class that means that list is constantly updated.

Comment: and when i say call, i simply mean, i want the dictionary list in the warehouse class to be searched through when asked in a different script @timgeb